# NVIDIA Tesla K80 VM instance won't start on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a VM instance on Google Cloud Compute attaching a NVIDIA Tesla K80 and using SSD for persistent storage.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it and stopped the instance to prevent billing during no-usage time. Now I try to start the instance again but it won't start, neither from Console nor from Terminal (macOS).

I have already tried to view the instance's console port log, but it's not available as the instance is not running.

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue by describing what error do you get while trying to start the instance? You can find the error from *Compute Engine> Operations* tab. Also, make sure you have followed all the [permission requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) to create and start a VM instance.

Comment: @Taher, the _Operations_ tab says only "INTERNAL_ERROR". I have also checked *Stackdriver Logging* and the last two messages say protoPayload:status:message:BACKEND_ERROR and jsonPayload:error:0:INTERNAL_ERROR.

Comment: I have also successfully stopped and started an instance before on another project. On that other instance I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a standard disk and without GPU, could the problem be related to the instance configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the preemptibility of your instance and GPU. You can check whether your GPU is preemptive or not from the [quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.234601112.705544661.1517265655-144889312.1508510367&_gac=1.245686960.1516416411.EAIaIQobChMIhNfAqcPl2AIVh4F-Ch1XMAugEAAYASAAEgIMevD_BwE).  You can check the preemptibility of your instance by clicking on the instance and finding out whether *Availability policy > Preemptibility* is **off** or **on**, or by following [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance#checking_if_an_instance_is_preemptible).

> Keep in mind, preemptible GPUs will only work on a preemptible instance.

If you find out that both the preemptibility matches, then it might be a project specific issue which will require one to one investigation. To get this support, you can open an issue in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) so someone from Google can assist you.